# visual studio cordova ios deploy for remote build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, visual-studio, cordova

My problem is

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Remote build error from the build server `http://xxxxxx:3000/cordova` - Derleme, Command to fetch XCode version failed. Your build may fail if the version installed is 8.0 or greater.

My Version:

```
Xcode version 7.2 
Cordova version     6.3.1
Node 4.4.3
Npm 2.15
Cordova android     5.2.1
Cordova iOS 4.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue previously, and I resolved it by go to my mac and accept the license agreement of xcode.

Run this in terminal :  sudo xcodebuild -license and then type agree.